# Match the start of each new line with JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with possible `\n` in them. Think of:

```
&nbsp;Foo1
&nbsp; Foo2
Foo3&nbsp; Foo4.
```

I want to replace `&nbsp;`'s at the start of each line, but the above is one string. `^nbsp;` only matches the first `&nbsp;` before `Foo1`. I want to do at the start of any newline, look for `&nbsp;`. Any ideas?

So, I want a regex that'll match the first two `&nbsp;`'s above, but not the 3rd.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to enable the `multiline` matching mode with `/m` flag, in order to match each line as a separate line.

```
/^(?:&nbsp;)+/gm
```